# Aggregate count matched conditional elements of nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB aggregation.

My DB has the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": "AAABBBCCCDDDD",
  "report":{
    "google": [{
        "report_id": "XXX",
        "detail": [{
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 300,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 400,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }]
    }, {
        "report_id": "YYY",
        "detail": [{
            "available": false,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ng",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }]
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to flatten the documents like this:

```
{
  "AAABBBCCCDDDD": [{
    "report_id": "XXX",
    "detail": [{
      "available": true,
      "status_code": 200,
      "return_code": "ok",
    }, {
      "available": true,
      "status_code": 300,
      "return_code": "ok",
    }, {
      "available": true,
      "status_code": 400,
      "return_code": "ok",
    }]
  }, {
    "report_id": "YYY",
    "detail": [{
      "available": false,
      "status_code": 200,
      "return_code": "ok",
    }, {
      "available": true,
      "status_code": 200,
      "return_code": "ng",
    }, {
      "available": true,
      "status_code": 200,
      "return_code": "ok",
    }]
  }]
}
```

then count how many matched `available is true` and `return_code is "ok"`, returning a structure like this:

```
{
  "AAABBBCCCDDDD": [{
    "report_id": "XXX",
    "available_count": 3,
  },
  {
    "report_id": "YYY",
    "available_count": 1,
  }]
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The "YYY" available count is actually 2 since there are 2 values of `true` in available.

Comment: The "YYY" available count should be 1 since the second element's return_code value is not "OK".

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that condition. Answer amended to include the other condition. I need to sleep now. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

With a modern MongoDB 3.4 you can do this with [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and `$arrayToObject`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            { 
              "k": "$_id", 
              "v": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$report.google",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": {
                    "report_id": "$$el.report_id",
                    "available_count": { 
                      "$size": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$el.detail",
                          "as": "d",
                          "cond": {
                           "$and": [
                             "$$d.available",
                             { "$eq": [ "$$d.return_code", "ok" ] }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But you can basically do this in any version with a little client side code:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc[doc._id] = doc.report.google.map(el => {
    el.available_count = el.detail.filter(d => d.available && d.return_code === "ok").length;
    delete el.detail;
    return el;
  });
  delete doc._id;
  delete doc.report;
  printjson(doc);
})
```

Both produce the same thing:

```js
{
        "AAABBBCCCDDDD" : [
                {
                        "report_id" : "XXX",
                        "available_count" : 3
                },
                {
                        "report_id" : "YYY",
                        "available_count" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

So you don't really need aggregation here at all since it's just really reshaping the document.

---

### Original Data from the Question as asked

```js
{
  "_id": "AAABBBCCCDDDD",
  "report":{
    "google": [{
        "report_id": "XXX",
        "detail": [{
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 300,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 400,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }]
    }, {
        "report_id": "YYY",
        "detail": [{
            "available": false,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ng",
        }, {
            "available": true,
            "status_code": 200,
            "return_code": "ok",
        }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Something was wrong when run it on  Mongo Shell.

2017-06-13T03:45:22.636+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "$arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: objectId",
 "code" : 40394,
 "codeName" : "Location40394"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5

Comment: @chenzww The answer does state very clearly at the beginning the to use `.aggregate()` with `$arrayToObject` you require [MongoDB 3,4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#apr-21-2017). I also state again very clearly that you "should" in fact not be using aggregate at all since the language based code to transform is very trivial and simple.

Comment: I confirm the version use "mongod --version" in terminal. It return "db version v3.4.4".
Then, execute "[{ "$limit": 1 }, {"$project": {"converted": {"$arrayToObject": {"$objectToArray":{"baka": true}}}}}]", and it return "{ "_id" : ObjectId("592b18616cd0bb578c7a9887"), "converted" : { "baka" : true } }". 
Every thing seems to work fine. What's the problem with my mongodb environment?

Comment: @chenzww If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The answer here is given to the question you asked, and works exactly as stated. At the risk of repeating myself for now the third time, not only does the aggregation statement work as listed here, but the lesson you "should" be learning is that you do not use aggregation for this type of operation at all. Manipulating the object requires "three" lines of code compared to the very terse aggregation operation. The output here is as listed run on my system from both methods provided.

Comment: First, nothing cannot be resolved without aggregation framework. As you said, manipulate the object is quite simple. However, I just want to know a way that just use mongodb.

Second, the raised error above may due to the fact that the value of "k" is not a string. It worked when I fill it with a string. Is it difficult to convert _id to string type?

Third, I don't know why available_count's value is always be "0" unless I comment out the '"$$d.available",' line.

Comment: @chenzww Understand this. I copied the data you supplied in your question. I wrote the statements you see above and run them against my MongoDB 3.4 instance. I then cut and paste the output from those commands into the answer. So everything here works. If you are getting errors then **you** are doing something wrong. Follow the same steps I have.

Comment: @chenzww This is the error you are getting. ` value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: objectId` because your "question" has the value of `_id` as a "string" however you are trying to apply this where items actually have `Objectid` values. That will not work for the exact reason the error message says. Now I got that error message from your other post, so now I know that in fact you are not doing exactly what I said. Copy your own data in your question "as is" and run the statements again. But you cannot make keys from numbers or objectid values.

Comment: I found out a mistake made since forgot replace "available" to "response_available".

Comment: @chenzww Your question as you asked it is answered. Please do not alter your question after it has already been answered. if you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This answers the question in the form it was originally asked. You have also been informed that it is not possible to use a value for a key which is not a string using the aggregation framework. You should accept the answer and simply move on.